# Летели дни(,) как стая белых птиц

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Летели дни(,) как стая белых птиц.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, с запятой нельзя:

*Летели дни как стая белых птиц*.

В переносном значении; то есть дни же не могут в прямом смысле лететь.

Дополнено.

В тексте щапятая всë-таки стоит. Думаю, потому, что оборот имеет значение уподобления:

*Летели дни, **подобно** стаям белый птиц*.

Об этом в [пунктике 3-1](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147).

Comment: Максим, а ведь это стихи. Лирические!  Как вы их прочитаете? В смысле пауз и ударений.

Comment: Думаю, с паузой перед _как_. Но паузы не всегда влияют на расстановку знаков. Влияют правила. Я всë же думаю, что запятая не нужна. Можете вставить свой ответ, высказав своé мнение. Я высказал своë, вы пишите своë.

Comment: Максим,  а почему обижаемся) У меня не критическое замечание, а лирическое отступление) Я как бы советуюсь с вами. // А вот правила не должны влиять на расстановку знаков, они просто правильно учитываются при их выборе, Мы должны записать то, что слышим в устной речи.  Особенно при декламации. //  Ответ? Не, мы тут с Лео вконец поссорились, я ему отвечать не буду)

Comment: @Sharon Обижаюсь?) Почему? Совсем не обижаюсь. Поссорились? Ну ладно, не отвечайте. Я просто своë мнение высказал пока что. Может, дополню, если найду что)

Comment: https://zvyki.com/song/72115256/Odin_za_vseh_-_Mihail_Boyarskij_-_Leteli_dni_iz_k_f_Vozvracshenie_mushketerov/